# Bizarre Problem with Wolfram Knowledgebase: Extracting Values

Tags: units

[System: Mas OS Mojave; Version: 11.3.0.0]

I tried to use the knowledgebase, because why not, but got a strange result:

[image: Trying to look up particle mass]

I also tried another lookup for good measure:

[image: Looking up country areas]

Plaintext code:

EntityValue[{Entity["Particle", "Proton"], 
  Entity["Particle", "Electron"]}, "Mass"]

Comment: Please post copyable code so that the issue can easily be reproduced.

Comment: These all work for me on Mathematica 11.3 on macOS Mojave. I'd [reset Mathematica to it's default configuration](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). You obviously are just having `QuantityUnits` paclet issues.

Comment: @user6014 it's probably better just to advise someone to delete the paclet I think. That solution is massive overkill in general and could easily destroy stuff a person has worked on for a while. I've mentioned this to WRI but they didn't seem to care. Also it requires one to reenter a validation key and one might not have that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reminder of best practice.

Resetting the program to its default configuration completely fixed it, and I'll keep that in my back pocket for the future.

1. Navigated to /Library/Mathematica (hidden by default)
2. Archived, then deleted all contents.
3. Rebooted Mathematica (had to re-enter validation key etc.)
4. Issue resolved.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that advice is *true trash*. It's an overkill solution to a minor problem and could have been fixed by simply deleting one or two of these folders or some more targeted thing. Not your fault. WRI really screwed you over.